# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

Tags: c++, xcode

Below is a function I need to use in main:

```
void determineDayOfBirth() {
cout << "Enter your date of birth" << endl;
cout << "format: month / day / year  --> ";

string userDate;

getline (cin, userDate);

string strmonth;
string strday;
string stryear;

auto first = userDate.find_first_of("/");
auto last = userDate.find_last_of("/");

strmonth = userDate.substr(0, first-1);
strday = userDate.substr(first+2, last-first-3);
stryear = userDate.substr(last+2, 4);

int userMonth = stoi(strmonth);
int userDay = stoi(strday);
int userYear = stoi(stryear);

if (isValidDate(userMonth, userDay, userYear)){
    cout << endl << "You were born on a: ";
    printDayOfBirth(determineDay(userMonth, userDay, userYear));
    cout << endl << "Have a great birthday!!!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Invalid date" << endl;
}

return;}
```

The function runs perfectly when main is like this:

```
int main(){

    int i=1;

    if (i==1){
        determineDayOfBirth();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I use cin to get i=1, it keeps showing that "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string". And I have to use cin to call the function because of the other part of the project. How could I fix it?

Comment: Please show the exact main function code that causes exception.

Comment: `int main(){
    
    int i;
    
    cin >> i;
    
    if (i==1){
        cout << i;
        determineDayOfBirth();
    }
    
    return 0;
}`